# asymptotic behavior of a matrix multiplying with a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, asymptotics, numerical-linear-algebra, characteristic-polynomial

I want to find the asympototic behaviors of $||M^nv||$ with some rate. [Just claiming that it's divergent is not enough - it requires finding some parallel bounds.]

We are given that M is 2x2 with characteristic polynomial $t^2-6t+9$.

(1) How does the asymptotic behavior of $||M^nv||$ have anything to do with diagonalizability of a matrix?

(2) I only saw that it simulates asymptotically to $3^nv$, but I was told that there is another situation involving $n-1$ somewhere. Is this the situation when it's diagonalizable or not? What is the other situation and how is it derived?

This is not a homework question and I don't really know which topic this problem belongs to. Any help with two questions above will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have two slightly different cases, as you suspected.

- In the diagonalizable case, in some basis you get $M=\pmatrix{3&0\\0&3}$ so that indeed $M^nv=3^nv$.
- In the non-diagonalizable case, there is a basis where you get the Jacobi normal form $M=\pmatrix{3&1\\0&3}$ so that $M^n=3^n\pmatrix{1&\frac{n}{3}\\0&1}$. So indeed, the norm (in the original basis) of the matrix-power-vector product can have components that behave like $n3^{n-1}$.

Comment: Hi. This is really helpful! I am wondering how you changed $M^n=3^n\pmatrix{1&\frac{n}{3}\\0&1} $ into $n3^{n-1}$. I get a feeling that it's through some norm so that we can take the n/3 from the corner down and throw out the remaining identity matrix, but I am not sure how this is formally done in a legit way. Your help will be appreciated!

Comment: I just multiplied the factor back in. As it is there, it can occur in all further expressions, and will dominate them for large $n$.